# Some errors trying to mount an SD card on Lubuntu 19.04 [-bash: mount/dev/x/mnt/sd: No such file or directory]

Tags: ubuntu, bash, mount, sd-card, error-correction

I’m trying to mount a SD card but I can’t, before these are the steps I made after create the folder `mnt/sd`, so definetly it exists. SD is `dev/mmcblk0`. Im new at Linux, so please try to be as clear as possible.

```
user@AsusNetbook-pc:~$ sudo -i
[sudo] password for user: 

root@AsusNetbook-pc:~# fdisk -l

Disk /dev/mmcblk1: 29,1 GiB, 31268536320 bytes, 61071360 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 7E07D4DF-1DB7-4D9D-887F-3B8DADE9FA82

Device            Start      End  Sectors  Size Type
/dev/mmcblk1p1       34  2099199  2099166    1G Linux filesystem
/dev/mmcblk1p2  2099200  2508799   409600  200M Microsoft basic data
/dev/mmcblk1p3  2508800 19286015 16777216    8G Linux swap
/dev/mmcblk1p4 19286016 50743295 31457280   15G Linux filesystem
/dev/mmcblk1p5 50743296 61071326 10328031  4,9G Linux filesystem


Disk /dev/mmcblk0: 119,3 GiB, 128041615360 bytes, 250081280 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x9347c459

Device         Boot Start       End   Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/mmcblk0p1 *     2048 250081279 250079232 119,3G  6 FAT16

root@AsusNetbook-pc:~# mount/dev/mmcblk0/mnt/sd
-bash: mount/dev/mmcblk0/mnt/sd: No such file or directory

root@AsusNetbook-pc:~# mount/dev/mmcblk0p1/mnt/sd
-bash: mount/dev/mmcblk0p1/mnt/sd: No such file or directory
```

*I have to add that that card must be formatted to work on Windows, I prefer don’t losing data, but if formatting on Windows (repair) and put it back to Lubuntu’s PC.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to separate the command (`mount`) from its operands and to separate the operands from each other. Example:

```
mount /dev/mmcblk0p1 /mnt/sd
#    ^    spaces    ^
```

Refer to `man 8 mount` to learn the syntax. In this simple case the syntax is like `mount what where`.

When you invoke

```
mount/dev/mmcblk0p1/mnt/sd
```

you're trying to run a file named `sd` in a directory `./mount/dev/mmcblk0p1/mnt/`. This file apparently does not exist. Even if it existed by chance, running it is not what you need to do in order to "mount a SD card".

Comment: Oh, okay i did it as you say and i got another issue :/ now the device doesnt exist: "root@AsusNetbook-pc:~# mount dev/mmcblk0 /mnt/SD
mount: /mnt/SD: special device dev/mmcblk0 does not exist.
root@AsusNetbook-pc:~# mount dev/mmcblk0p1 /mnt/SD
mount: /mnt/SD: special device dev/mmcblk0p1 does not exist."

Comment: @beetracker Note I wrote `/dev/mmcblk0p1` with a leading slash; it's important. Also I don't think you want to mount the entire device `mmcblk0`; if there is a partition table there (and your `fdisk` says there is) then there is *most likely* no filesystem there you can mount.

Comment: sorry about that annoying mistake by my part, i already wrote it properly and now it says: "wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/mmcblk0p1, missing codepage or helper program, or other error"

Comment: @beetracker One issue – one question. Your original issue (no spaces) is solved. Please ask a new question.